# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmouseover' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ive been working on creating a swinging effect in javascript so that a number of objects, when the mouse moves over them will however and then slowly keep hovering until they stop.

I have got this working in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z3s7v/58/

Here is the Js that I have:

```
(function(){

var box=document.getElementById('box');box2=document.getElementById('box2');box3=document.getElementById('box3');

swing(box);swing(box2);swing(box3);

function swing(box) {
  var ang  = 20,
   dAng = 10,
   ddAng = .5,
   dir  = 1;

function setAng(ang){
box.style.WebkitTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';
box.style.MozTransform =  'rotate('+ang+'deg)';
dir = -dir;
if (dAng > 1)
    dAng -= ddAng;

if (Math.abs(ang) > 0)
    setTimeout(setAng, 1000, dir * (Math.abs(ang)-dAng));
};

box.onmouseover = function(){    
box.style.WebkitTransform =  'rotate(-20deg)';
box.style.MozTransform =  'rotate(-20deg)';
setTimeout(function(){
    setAng(ang)
}, 1000);
}

};
}())
```

Also as a second question if anyone can answer this, the more boxes I add the jerkier and more rigid the swinging seems to be.

Appreciate all the help folks.

Comment: Why are you not using jQuery if you have it included and tagged?

Comment: Please choose the jQuery Lib from the left side menu in your fiddle. It works!!!

Comment: It works http://jsfiddle.net/z3s7v/59/

Comment: I have already said that it works on JSFiddle it. Doesnt work in a web page

Answer (score 3):

Wrap code in

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    // your code 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be because you are trying to set the variable before the elements are loaded so the variable gets set to null. the way to fix this would be to go into your html file and replace this:

```
<script src="path/to/file.js" ></script>
```

with this

```
<script defer src="path/to/file.js" ></script>
```

so by adding the `defer` attribute, you tell the browser to execute you javasctipt after the page is loaded.

I know this is a little late but I found the solution so here you go.